# SYCL No kernel named was found -46 (CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME)

Tags: sycl

The following c++ SYCL code works only using host device, using GPU device (NVIDIA or INTEL) I have the following error:

No kernel named _ZTSZZN10MainWindow15testPerformanceEiENKUlRN2cl4sycl7handlerEE_clES3_E10FillBuffer was found -46 (CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME)

thanks in advance.

```
std::vector<sycl::platform> all_platforms = sycl::platform::get_platforms();
    cl::sycl::device selectedDevice;

    if (all_platforms.size()==0)
    {
        std::cout<<" No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        return;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < all_platforms.size(); i++)
    {
        sycl::platform  current_platform = all_platforms[i];

        std::vector<sycl::device> all_devices = current_platform.get_devices();

        // Loop over all devices available from this platform.
        for( const cl::sycl::device& device : all_devices )
        {
            QString type;

            if(device.is_gpu())
            {
                selectedDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    sycl::queue myQueue(selectedDevice);

    try
    {
        myQueue.submit([&](sycl::handler &h) {
            sycl::stream os(1024, 768, h);
            h.parallel_for<class FillBuffer>(32, [=](sycl::id<1> i) {
                os<<i<<"\n";
              });
          }).wait();
    }
    catch (cl::sycl::exception ex)
    {
        std::cout << "cl::sycl::exception+: " << ex.what() << " category: " << ex.category().name()  << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was releated to qmake autogenerated Makafile parameter order

WRONG WAY (auto generated):

```
$(LINKER) $(LFLAGS) /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:$(DESTDIR_TARGET) @<<
debug\main.obj debug\mainwindow.obj debug\moc_mainwindow.obj
$(LIBS)
<<
```

CORRECT WAY:

```
    $(LINKER) debug\main.obj debug\mainwindow.obj debug\moc_mainwindow.obj $(LFLAGS) /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:$(DESTDIR_TARGET) @<<
$(LIBS)
<<
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a namespace related issue from first check.

Instead of

```
h.parallel_for<class FillBuffer>(32, [=](sycl::id<1> i) {
                os<<i<<"\n";
              });
```

Declare `class FillBuffer`; at the top of your file, then use

```
h.parallel_for<FillBuffer>(32, [=](sycl::id<1> i) {
                os<<i<<"\n";
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in my cmake project due to C and CXX enabled as the default languages. Wrong compiler/linker is used in such case. Setting `project(projectName CXX)` fixed it and compilation now works with the specified SYCL compiler.